# Installing FreeDOS from Linux

Tags: linux, ms-dos

I need to install [minimal] FreeDOS in a machine already running Linux, without a CD drive. I already have another FAT32 target partition.

I've already runned "sys-freedos-linux" but it just installs the bootsector and says I have to copy KERNEL.SYS and COMMAND.COM files mannually. Where do I find those files (freedos iso has only KERNEL16.SYS and KERNEL32.SYS files)? Do I place them at root? Is this ALL I need to boot into a basic FreeDOS installation (I just need it in order to initialize an WinNT installation...)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't have the newest version of the FreeDOS ISO. The file kernelx.zip on [version 1.1](http://www.freedos.org/download/) of the ISO contains KERNEL.SYS (and commandx.zip contains COMMAND.COM). Just copy these files to the root of the partition. This should work provided you already have:
1) FreeDOS boot loader in the boot record of the target partition (which will load KERNEL.SYS). I guess "sys-freedos-linux" installed this.
2) Some boot loader in the master boot record of the disk (which loades the FreeDOS boot loader). This can be GRUB, the default DOS MBR code or something else. It might require the target partition to be marked as bootable to work.

Since you have to craft your own DOS partition like this I assume you lack the possibility to install from either floppy or CD on the target machine. Another alternative (which might even let you skip the step of booting DOS to begin with) is to make the installation using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (to the target disk directly or to an image you can write to the target disk).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to boot FreeDOS using GRUB from your Linux installation.

You might find this helpful: http://hype-free.blogspot.de/2008/12/booting-freedos-with-grub.html

Comment: No, by menu.lst entry is OK. The question is how to actually install a minimal FreeDOS into the target partition from Linux (since I don't have a CD drive nor USB ports)